# Replot figure only at the end of a panel resize event

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm currently trying to improve plotting part of a software.

We are using WXPython and Matplotlib in order to show user many plots with various controls over them.

To sum up, here is the context:

[image: Context]

Matplotlib performance is fine for our plotting needs, however, resizing our wxpython main frame is resizing wx panels that contains matplotlib canvas.

(At each step or the resizing, and not only at the end)

Resizing panels if fast, but matplotlib is also redrawing canvas and figures at each steps of the resizing, creating visual freezes and some lag.

To sum up, the problem:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable (temporary) matplotlib events/auto-redrawing stuff, during our WX Frame resize event, then apply a redraw at the end of it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only half of an answer, because (1) I use PyQt here instead of WX, and (2) it only shows how to prevent the resizing from happening, such that it can later be done manually.

The idea is to subclass the `FigureCanvas` and take over the `resizeEvent` method. In this method only store the resize event, but don't let it happen.
Later manually trigger the event.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

class MyFigureCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """ Subclass canvas to catch the resize event """
    def __init__(self, figure):
        self.lastEvent = False # store the last resize event's size here
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, figure)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if not self.lastEvent:
            # at the start of the app, allow resizing to happen.
            super(MyFigureCanvas, self).resizeEvent(event)
        # store the event size for later use
        self.lastEvent = (event.size().width(),event.size().height())
        print "try to resize, I don't let you."

    def do_resize_now(self):
        # recall last resize event's size
        newsize = QtCore.QSize(self.lastEvent[0],self.lastEvent[1] )
        # create new event from the stored size
        event = QtGui.QResizeEvent(newsize, QtCore.QSize(1, 1))
        print "Now I let you resize."
        # and propagate the event to let the canvas resize.
        super(MyFigureCanvas, self).resizeEvent(event)


class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.fig = Figure()
        # use subclassed FigureCanvas
        self.canvas = MyFigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Manually Resize")        
        l.addWidget(self.button)
        l.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.action)     
        self.plot()

    def action(self):
        # when button is clicked, resize the canvas.
        self.canvas.do_resize_now()

    def plot(self):
        # just some random plots
        self.axes = []
        for i in range(4):
            ax = self.fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1)
            a = np.random.rand(100,100)
            ax.imshow(a)
            self.axes.append(ax)
        self.fig.tight_layout()


qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
aw = ApplicationWindow()
aw.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

It could be that doing this in WX is not too different.

Comment: Nice solution, but it doesn't address the problem of redrawing the plots at the end of the resize. However, that can be solved by [installing](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.installEventFilter) an [`eventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.eventFilter) that runs `self.canvas.do_resize_now()` if `event.type()` is either a `MouseButtonRelease` or a `NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease` (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45830212/1070480)).

Comment: `do_resize_now` should also be called if the event is of the type `WindowStateChange`. Besides, if the canvas is in a `QDockWidget`, the signals [`visibilityChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#visibilityChanged) and [`dockLocationChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#dockLocationChanged) may need to be [connected](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots) to `do_resize_now`.

Comment: Furthermore, it might be a good idea to check whether the canvas has actually been resized by comparing the new size with the previous size before calling `super(MyFigureCanvas, self).resizeEvent`, otherwise the plot is in some circumstances going to be redrawn even though it's size hasn't changed.

Comment: Finally, `QTimer.singleShot(0, do_resize_now)` might have to be done instead of calling `do_resize_now` directly in some circumstances (always calling `QTimer.singleShot` doesn't hurt), since the update of the canvas size may have been queued in the event queue.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye This answer uses a button, which has to be pressed to trigger the redrawing. If instead you wanted to automatically have it redraw, all those points would indeed apply.